# how to provide authoriztion to databases in couchdb?

Tags: java, security, gwt, couchdb

I want to provide authorization to my databases  for its security.
providing authorization has two phase one with futon the GUI of couch db and the accessibility through java code.

I secured a particular database through security object on futon, its like I have decided here that which user can only access that database on futon. but in this condition through code we can't perform any operation on database and get the following error.

I am trying this code to access database

`Session studentDbSession = new Session("localhost",5984,"engg","engg");`
`Database studentCouchDb = studentDbSession.getDatabase("notifications");`

notification is my secured database.

**Error:**

Jul 2, 2014 1:39:06 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector isAuthenticationNeeded
INFO: Authentication requested but doAuthentication is disabled
Jul 2, 2014 1:39:06 PM com.fourspaces.couchdb.Session getDatabase
WARNING: Error getting database: notifications

exception ::java.lang.NullPointerException

**My Question:**

So, I want to know how to access secured database through coding, so that every one is not permitted to access all database.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with java so I will just write about how it can be done via the default rest api:-

Everything you need to know about authentication is in the [documentation](https://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/database/security.html)

The simplest way is to use the basic authentication scheme

`http://username:password@localhost:5984/`

You will need to send credentials with every request and if you are using `pbkdf2`(default) scheme this can lead to slow performance.

Then you have cookie based authentication. For this you will need to `post`, `name` and `password` to `_session` handler and couchdb will give you back a cookie. Then just send this cookie with requests you need to be authenticated.

So all you need to know is how to `post` with the java http library that you are using. Then in the response that is returned save the cookie in a variable and send it with requests that must be authenticated.

There is also oauth and proxy authentication but I think cookie based and simple should be good enough for your requirement.